# Unable to capture a web page fully using WebBrowser control

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I am using `WebBrowser` control to capture a web page as an image.
I am using the .NET Framework and Visual C#.

I have posted the same question in MSDN forums for help.

Below is the URL:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ab405505-f71d-4130-88e7-b43a8f3a6dce/unable-to-capture-a-web-page-fully-using-webbrowser-control

I tried with the suggested code in the above MSDN link and also tried with IECapture.

In all the above approaches the web page is partially captured for the URL I am trying.

The code I am using is as follows:

```
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Threading;

namespace Capture
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            Thread thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(SaveWebPage2Image));
            thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA); thread.Start(); thread.Join();
            while (thread.IsAlive) System.Windows.Forms.Application.DoEvents();

        }
        public void SaveWebPage2Image()
        {

            //string url = "https://qaweb1.brassring.com/JetStream/500/Presentation/Template/ASP/Candidate/Forms/ViewForm.asp?isgq=@s/8UkTuFFVU=&apprvl=@Qa8WrdFDvAg=&localeid=@IsSbRwlc1jxKpUy0SbstnA==&mode=@1yjS1Hi6/q/uNq32m6X08Q==&where=@TPEBTmFaU8Z5hrgmRqSygA==&encryptedvalues=@frA9V1Hg3yGPn/WR$lE0ZQ==*@s8G9/N7ZuBBDPNEIdP93OY7FbF6jdmLQ*@nJVB$mLvi5GYIetk2PPrKg==*@6VgXPbEuLtM=*@TxInxLRUFyv6ynZ$0AidTA==*@p$qzP$A6PVQCNoPvNsVIig==*@7jmvKabnpHc=*@y5hagH778g$HcfEEpp27ow==*@O6v$zI0Rg4x2CI21$4eh5w==*@amtcAhHDhl8=**@7jmvKabnpHc=*@s/8UkTuFFVU=";
            //string url = "https://qaweb1.brassring.com/JetStream/500/Presentation/Template/ASP/Candidate/Forms/ViewForm.asp?isgq=@7jmvKabnpHc=&apprvl=&localeid=@IsSbRwlc1jxKpUy0SbstnA==&mode=@1yjS1Hi6/q/uNq32m6X08Q==&where=@TPEBTmFaU8Z5hrgmRqSygA==&ImagePDF=true&encryptedvalues=@Uc1WQ3WL4FE=*@G6OALy2D/Sw=*@NSsHy5JAJU4=*@G6OALy2D/Sw=*@l50gSO4U$PgdNsC8UgqqPg==*@e6jizcAy9VaSMwWeuzhEpg==*@7jmvKabnpHc=*@HmtaehYz7ddx7pzp1/zn7g==*@OmlYofN7vBtVHlkn6N9HHQ==*@gkqEz1ALh58=**@s/8UkTuFFVU=*";
            string url = "https://staging.brassring.com/JetStream/500/Presentation/Template/ASP/Candidate/Forms/ViewForm.asp?isgq=@7jmvKabnpHc=&apprvl=&localeid=@IsSbRwlc1jxKpUy0SbstnA==&mode=@1yjS1Hi6/q/uNq32m6X08Q==&where=@TPEBTmFaU8Z5hrgmRqSygA==&ImagePDF=true&encryptedvalues=@beNISxIeqdbTwJDcENDNrw==*@G6OALy2D/Sw=*@RmN4OccrJCjwYUoIljGjkg==*@G6OALy2D/Sw=*@6QMkrwY3rBRhOisaSOgfLdhs5hiR$w3l*@JUzenvUf5Xc=*@7jmvKabnpHc=*@0HjV7NCQJmwZepqHbZpMsf0G5RB9W/iy*@gUULJEM726$QfVXNUh$Tpw==*@amtcAhHDhl8=**@s/8UkTuFFVU=*";

            // Load the webpage into a WebBrowser control
            WebBrowser wb;
            wb = new WebBrowser();

            wb.DocumentCompleted += new WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(CaptureImage);
            wb.Navigate(url);

            while (wb.ReadyState != WebBrowserReadyState.Complete) { System.Windows.Forms.Application.DoEvents(); }

        }

        private void CaptureImage(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Url.AbsolutePath != (sender as WebBrowser).Url.AbsolutePath)
                return;
            WebBrowser wb = sender as WebBrowser;
            wb.ScrollBarsEnabled = false;
            wb.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true;
            // Take Screenshot of the web pages full width
            //wb.Width = wb.Document.Body.ScrollRectangle.Width;
            int wbwidth =wb.Document.Body.ScrollRectangle.Width ;
            // Take Screenshot of the web pages full height
            int wbheight = wb.Document.Body.ScrollRectangle.Height;

            // Get a Bitmap representation of the webpage as it's rendered in the WebBrowser control
            Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(wbwidth, wbheight);
            wb.Size = new Size(wbwidth, wbheight);          


            wb.DrawToBitmap(bitmap, new Rectangle(0,0,  wb.Width, wb.Height));
            //wb.Dispose();

            bitmap.Save(@"C:\web-shot.png", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
            bitmap.Dispose();


        }
    }
}
```

Please see the output image:

[image: Output Image]

Please open the URL

[Link To the Web Page](https://staging.brassring.com/JetStream/500/Presentation/Template/ASP/Candidate/Forms/ViewForm.asp?isgq=@7jmvKabnpHc=&apprvl=&localeid=@IsSbRwlc1jxKpUy0SbstnA==&mode=@1yjS1Hi6/q/uNq32m6X08Q==&where=@TPEBTmFaU8Z5hrgmRqSygA==&ImagePDF=true&encryptedvalues=@beNISxIeqdbTwJDcENDNrw==*@G6OALy2D/Sw=*@RmN4OccrJCjwYUoIljGjkg==*@G6OALy2D/Sw=*@6QMkrwY3rBRhOisaSOgfLdhs5hiR$w3l*@JUzenvUf5Xc=*@7jmvKabnpHc=*@0HjV7NCQJmwZepqHbZpMsf0G5RB9W/iy*@gUULJEM726$QfVXNUh$Tpw==*@amtcAhHDhl8=**@s/8UkTuFFVU=*)

in a browser and compare it with the above output image file then you will see that some fields are missing in the captured image.

Please look into this issue and help me to resolve this issue..

Please let me know if you need more information.

Comment: What is the exact problem you encounter?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by 'partially'? Do you have a sample image?

Comment: Yes I have a image..As I am new to this forum..It said I need 10 points to post images..so I am unable to post the image..Can you suggest me is there anyway I can give you the image ?

Comment: Host the image somewhere and edit your question to add the link. Someone will be able to edit your question then with the image.

Comment: I have added the link to the image.. Please open the URL  [link](https://staging.brassring.com/JetStream/500/Presentation/Template/ASP/Candidate/Forms/ViewForm.asp?isgq=@7jmvKabnpHc=&apprvl=&localeid=@IsSbRwlc1jxKpUy0SbstnA==&mode=@1yjS1Hi6/q/uNq32m6X08Q==&where=@TPEBTmFaU8Z5hrgmRqSygA==&ImagePDF=true&encryptedvalues=@beNISxIeqdbTwJDcENDNrw==*@G6OALy2D/Sw=*@RmN4OccrJCjwYUoIljGjkg==*@G6OALy2D/Sw=*@6QMkrwY3rBRhOisaSOgfLdhs5hiR$w3l*@JUzenvUf5Xc=*@7jmvKabnpHc=*@0HjV7NCQJmwZepqHbZpMsf0G5RB9W/iy*@gUULJEM726$QfVXNUh$Tpw==*@amtcAhHDhl8=**@s/8UkTuFFVU=*) in a browser and compare it with the outputimage

Answer (score 1):

Here is a sample:

```
public Bitmap GenerateScreenshot(string url, int width, int height)
    {
        WebBrowser wb = new WebBrowser();
        wb.ScrollBarsEnabled = false;
        wb.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true;
        wb.Navigate(url);
        while (wb.ReadyState != WebBrowserReadyState.Complete) { Application.DoEvents(); }

        wb.Width = width;
        wb.Height = height;

        if (width == -1)
        {
            wb.Width = wb.Document.Body.ScrollRectangle.Width;
        }

        if (height == -1)
        {
            wb.Height = wb.Document.Body.ScrollRectangle.Height;
        }

        Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(wb.Width, wb.Height);
        wb.DrawToBitmap(bitmap, new Rectangle(0, 0, wb.Width, wb.Height));
        wb.Dispose();

        return bitmap;
    }
```

This is how you use it :

```
// Generate thumbnail of a webpage at 1024x768 resolution
Bitmap thumbnail = GenerateScreenshot("http://pietschsoft.com", 1024, 768);

// Generate thumbnail of a webpage at the webpage's full size (height and width)
thumbnail = GenerateScreenshot("http://pietschsoft.com");

// Display Thumbnail in PictureBox control
pictureBox1.Image = thumbnail;

// Save Thumbnail to a File
thumbnail.Save("thumbnail.png", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
```

This code is from [http://pietschsoft.com/](http://pietschsoft.com/post/2008/07/C-Generate-WebPage-Thumbmail-Screenshot-Image.aspx)